# Does a stack allocated array gets automatically zero-initialized?

Tags: c++

If I do something like this:

```
int myArray[5];
```

Is that array automatically zero-initialized? If not, how can I declare a stack allocated, zero-initialized array?

I know that for heap allocated arrays, I can do:

```
int* myArray = new int[5]();
```

Thanks anyway :)

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: You can simply assign it to zero which will implicitly call memset.
`int myArray[5] = {0};`

Comment: If you mean *how do I initialise every element to 0* then a `for` loop is your answer, right now the array is filled with junk data

Comment: `int myArray[5]{};` or `int myArray[5] = {};` will zero-initialize it.

Comment: `int myArray[5]{};` to zero-initialize. `{}` should initialize any object to a sensible null/zero/empty state if its type has such a state as long as the type isn't poorly designed. (An infamous exception to that being e.g. `std::atomic` because of C compatibility considerations.)

Comment: @Irelia That form is somewhat misleading, since the specified number is used only for the first element. E.g. `= {1}` would give you `{1,0,0,0,0}`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It is however the most well-known, since it is the only form that has always been allowed in C and C++.

Comment: @Karlos - It is a good idea to *always* be explicit on initialization. In places where the variables would be zeroed anyway (like global data), an extra `= {}` does no harm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the initial values of the array are uninitialized values (ie undefined). They don't get initialized to zero in c++;

To explicitly initialized the array to zero, you can use the following syntax:

```
int myarray[5]{};      // Yes it would be nice to use int myarray[5]();
                       // Like you did with dynamic allocation.
                       // But of course the most vexing parse kicks in
                       // So we added '{}` as an alternative to `()`
                       // to get around this small issues.

// Of course there are a couple of alternatives
// From the original syntax.
int myarray[5]={0};    // From: C (paraphrasing)
                       // If the list of values in an array
                       // initializer is not long enough for the
                       // array it is expanded with 0 to
                       // make sure the list matches the length
                       // of the array.
```

This is the standard way to initialize the array element to zero in c++;

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: C++ is not C, `{0}` can be `{}`. Even shorter `int myarray[5]{};`

Comment: @273K Sidenote: Empty brace initialiser will be allowed in the upcoming C2x standard as well.

Comment: Yes, we can use this syntax as well.